# Sugar daddy needs pictures of my credit card — scam or not?

Tags: credit-card, scams, sugar-daddy

I met this guy. I've been talking to him for two weeks. I'm too shy to meet him. He wants to pay my credit card. To pay it he needs a full picture of both sides on my credit card. Do I give it to him or is it a scam?

Comment: Any question of the form "...sugar daddy, ..., scam or not?", the answer is yes.

Comment: Out of genuine curiosity/bafflement, what do you think the "sugar" part of "sugar daddy" means?

Comment: This is not even an elaborate scam. No transfer of money and then send some back and the original bounces a month later. This is just outright give me everything I need to use your card to make online purchases. It’s like the scammers are not even putting in effort.

Comment: Not only that, I don't think he could actually pay the credit card just knowing the info on the card.  He'd have to have your user name & password on the card's online system, or (if you're still using paper mail) the payment slip from the credit card bill.

Comment: @jamesqf: I pay most of my cards by 'bill pay' (ACH credit) from my bank, and it requires only choosing the recipient (here the issuing bank) from a list and entering the card number. Even without that I'm sure if I phoned the customer (dis)service number on the back of the card and told them I needed help making a payment they would find a way I could do so :-} That said, I agree _this_ person isn't going to make any payment.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 *bill pay* is also how I pay my CC.  If it's not one of the Big 10 CC companies, then you need to enter the mailing address and phone number, in addition to the CC bank and number.  But they sure don't care whether it's **your** account, and neither does the bank.  Ditto on mortgages, auto loans, etc.

Comment: Phone number is on the back of the card. Call that number, type in the card number, provide a payment method (bank account or debit card), and you can pay the bill. You don't need to use the issuing bank's online banking portal and you don't need any other info. Even if you wanted to pay via check, just look up the bank's address online and mail a check with the account number written in the memo line. Check digitizing systems used by banks automatically look for account numbers in memo lines, you don't actually need a payment slip. All that said, this is clearly a scam.

Comment: @Damila It's like they're not putting in effort because they don't have to, by the looks of things.  Just based on the number of questions we see about this here where people consider it, I imagine there must be people who fall for this all the time.

Comment: @JMac, on the other hand, it makes things easier for the victim too. No opening an account at one-branch credit union in a 2000 population town on the other side of the country.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a scam.

To use a credit card on-line, you typically need 4 things: the name on the account, the account number, the expiration date, and the CVV number. The first three are on the front of your card; the last is on the back.

If you send him the images, you will not see any payments on your card. You will, however, see a bunch of charges that you will be responsible for.

Comment: minor nitpicking: you need the card number, not the account number; also one of my cards has only the name on the front and the rest of the info on the back, so it varies based on the card/bank.

Comment: True, I'm thinking of standard credit cards, where the card number *is* the account number, but I think that's changing. Come to think of it, a fun prank might be to send the scammer images of a card that doesn't have any of this information (e.g., an Apple Card) physically on the card. (But seriously, OP: don't engage the scammer further. Ghost him.)

Answer (score 11):

Honestly... when **you** want to send money to a friend, you'd use PayPal, Zelle, Venmo, Cashapp, or some other modern digital method, right?

So would he, if he **really** wanted to pay off your credit cards.

Answer (score 1):

He could just send you cash. This is a scam.

Comment: Paper doesn't transmit very well over the Internet.

Comment: I upvoted to offset a negative vote. This is not the best answer, but it is true.

Comment: @RonJohn: Strange as it may seem, many places still have actual snail mail service :-)

Comment: @jamesqf when was the last time you recommended sending **cash** through the mail.

Comment: @RonJon you're not wrong that sending cash is foolish, but also-- this absolutely a scam, and there's no benefit whatsoever to giving this 'sugar daddy' any information.

Comment: @NegativeFriction you didn't read **my** answer, did you?

Comment: @RonJohn: Probably the last time I tried to seduce some naive young (possibly under age?) woman over the internet :-)  That is, if I cared to make a transaction pretty well untracable, I would send cash (and probably rinse the bills in a dilute bleach solution or similar to remove trace DNA), since the risk of having money stolen in the mail is far lower than the risk of arrest.

Comment: @jamesqf why did you assume that OP is underage?  (They don't get issued many credit cards that are independent of their parents.)

Comment: @RonJohn: I'm not assuming that (notice I said POSSIBLY?), just suggesting it as one of the many things that might happen on the internet, and would give the person doing it a good reason to keep his identity well-concealed.

Comment: Jeez I didn't mean actual paper money. I meant Venmo or something.